Polyhedron and their vertices as a function with respect to the constrains
Fix a matrix $A$ of size $n\times m$, and let $P(v):=\{w\in \mathbb{R}^m:Aw+v\geq 0\}$ where we view $v$ as an variable. Then let $E(P(v))$ be the set of vertices of the polyhedron $P(v)$, and let $I(v):=\{\mathrm{EqSub}(e):e\in E(P(v))\}$ where $\mathrm{EqSub}(e)\subseteq\{1,2,...,n\}$ is the set of indices where the equality happens (i.e. the equality subsystem of $Ae+v\geq 0$)
Then, note this set $L_A:=\{I(v):v\in \mathbb{Z}^n\}$ is finite, since there are only finitely many subsets of the power set of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.
I'm interested in:

how to determine this set $L_A$ for a given $A$
how to compute $I(v)$ for a fixed $v$
how to determine the region where $I(v)$ is constant

Attempts:
I'm not sure how to even work out low-dimension examples (at the same time with sufficient complexity/not too degenerated so it occurs on what I'm working on), but here is an attempt: say we have $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 2 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$ Then by sampling through a cube $[-10,10]^4$, it seems the possible indices are given by (index start at 0):

[[0, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 3]]
[[0, 1], [1, 3]]
[[2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 2], [2, 3]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
[[0, 2, 3]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [1, 2]]

My guess is $I(v)$ should equal $I(v+\lambda \vec{1})$, and if that's true then the above is probably a fairly complete list, but not sure how to prove it.

What is your work on this theme ? Have you for example something to say for the case $m=2$ ?

@JeanMarie I currently have a heuristic/guess on what they are, but not sure if they are correct or not. In fact, I'm not sure how to even compute those in the case of m=2... Let me see if I can come up with some examples...

Your notation for indices is inconsistent : in $\mathrm{EqSub}(e)\subseteq{1,2,...,n}$ they start from $1$, but at the end of the OP they start from $0$. I advise you to consistently start from $1$, which is the standard usage for matrix-related indices.

In theory, all you need to do to answer all of 1,2 and 3, is simply to unroll
the definitions and compute all the facets of $P(v)$. Formally, if we denote by
$\alpha_i(w)$ the linear form given by the $i$-th line of $A$, then $P(v)$ is defined
by the $n$ inequalities $\alpha_i(w)\geq v_i (1\leq i \leq n)$, and a generic facet of
$P(v)$ is of the form
$$
P_J(v)=\lbrace w \in P(v) \ \bigg| \ \phi_i(w)=v_i \ (i\in J)\rbrace \tag{1}
$$
where $J\subseteq [1...n]$.
Now you usually don't need to compute each of the $2^n$ $P_J(v)$'s separately, of course ;
some $P_J(v)$'s will be empty, and different $J$'s may give the same $P_J(v)$. So it usually
pays to guess in advance a good order in which to make the computations ; this order will depend
on the particular form of the $A$ you're dealing with.
Now let us see how it all works on the numerical example you gave. We start by the looking at the
faces of $P(v)$ (or simply $P$ in shorthand notation) :
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
P_1 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in P \ \bigg| \ x_1 = v_1 \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_2 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in P \ \bigg| \ x_1 = v_2 \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_3 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in P \ \bigg| \ -x_1+2x_2 = v_3 \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_4 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in P \ \bigg| \ -x_1+x_2 = v_4 \bigg\rbrace. \\
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$
It is straightforward to check that
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
P_1 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}  \ \bigg| \ x_2 \geq \max(v_2,\frac{v_1+v_3}{2},v_1+v_4) \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_2 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}  \ \bigg| \ v_1 \leq x_1 \leq \min(2v_2-v_3,v_2-v_4) \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_3 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} 2x_2-v_3 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}  \ \bigg| \ \max(v_2,\frac{v_1+v_3}{2}) \leq x_2 \leq v_3-v_4 \bigg\rbrace, \\
P_4 &=& \bigg\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1+v_4 \end{pmatrix}  \ \bigg| \ x_1 \geq \max(v_1,v_2-v_4,v_3-2v_4) \bigg\rbrace. \\
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$
Which leads us, after a little bit of trial and error, to the following disjunction of eleven cases :

Here are the faces :
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \textrm{Case} & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4  \\
\hline
1 & x_2 \geq v_2 & 
 v_1 \leq x_1 \leq 2v_2-v_3 & 
 v_2 \leq x_2 \leq v_3-v_4  & 
  x_1 \geq v_3-2v_4  \\
\hline
2 & 
x_2 \geq v_2 & 
 v_1 \leq x_1 \leq 2v_2-v_3 & 
 x_2 = v_2  & 
  x_1 \geq 2v_2-v_3  \\
\hline
3   & 
x_2 \geq v_2 & 
 v_1 \leq x_1 \leq v_2-v_4 &
 \emptyset & 
  x_1 \geq v_2-v_4   
 \\
\hline
4  & 
x_2 \geq v_1 & 
 \emptyset & 
 x_2 = v_2  & 
  x_1 \geq v_1  \\
\hline
5  & 
x_2 \geq v_1+v_4 & 
 \emptyset & 
 \emptyset  & 
  x_1 \geq v_3-2v_4  \\
\hline
6  & 
x_2 \geq v_2 & 
 x_1 = v_1 & 
 v_2 \leq x_2 \leq 2v_2-v_1-v_4 & 
  x_1 \geq 2v_2-v_1-2v_4  \\
\hline
7  & 
x_2 \geq v_2 & 
 x_1 = v_1 & 
 x_2 = v_2 & 
  x_1 \geq v_1  \\
\hline
8  & 
x_2 \geq v_1+v_4 & 
 \emptyset & 
 \emptyset  & 
  x_1 \geq v_1  \\
\hline
9  & 
x_2 \geq \frac{v_1+v_3}{2} & 
 \emptyset & 
 \frac{v_1+v_3}{2} \leq x_2 \leq v_3-v_4  & 
  x_1 \geq v_3-2v_4  \\
\hline
10  & 
x_2 \geq \frac{v_1+v_3}{2} & 
 \emptyset & 
 x_1=\frac{v_1+v_3}{2}   & 
  x_1 \geq v_1  \\
\hline
11 & 
x_2 \geq v_1+v_4 & 
 \emptyset & 
 \emptyset & 
  x_1 \geq v_1  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
And the vertices with their index set :
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \textrm{Case} &  E(P(v)) & I(v) \\
\hline
1 &  
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} 2v_2-v_3 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_3-2v_4 \\ v_3-v_4 \end{pmatrix}     & 12,23,34 \\
\hline
2 & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} 2v_2-v_3 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix} 2v_2-v_3 \\ 2v_2-v_3+v_4 \end{pmatrix}    & 12,23,4 \\
\hline
3   & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_2-v_4 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}     & 12,24 \\
\hline
4  &
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_1+v_4 \end{pmatrix}    & 12,4 \\
\hline
5  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1+v_4 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_3-2v_4 \\ v_3-v_4 \end{pmatrix}    & 1,4 \\
\hline
6  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} 2v_2-v_3 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix} 2v_2-v_1-2v_4 \\ 2v_2-v_1-v_4 \end{pmatrix}    & 12,3,34 \\
\hline
7  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}    & 1234 \\
\hline
8  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_1+v_4 \end{pmatrix}    & 14 \\
\hline
9  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \frac{v_1+v_3}{2} \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_3-2v_4 \\ v_3-v_4 \end{pmatrix}     & 13,34 \\
\hline
10  & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \frac{v_1+v_3}{2} \end{pmatrix}     & 134 \\
\hline
11 & 
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_1+v_4 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} v_3-2v_4 \\ v_3-v_4 \end{pmatrix}     & 14 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
